# What is the difference between {{ }} and {{{ }}} in laravel blade files?

Tags: laravel

In the laravel framework we can use blade to add PHP code in html file.
We are using both `{{ }} and {{{ }}}` syntax in blade files of Laravel. 
What is the difference between them?

i have a code in a blade file like this

```
{{{ $errors->has('slider') ? 'has-error' : '' }}}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference between `{{ }}` and `{{{ }}}` in Laravel 5 at all.

> In version 4 it included the following two styles: “{{” and “{{{“. The double
>   curly bracket was a raw echo and the triple curly bracket escaped.
>
> Currently in 5.0 both the double and triple curly brackets escape the
>   variable and a new “{!! $var !!}” is for raw.

https://laravel-news.com/2014/09/laravel-5-0-blade-changes/

Answer (score 15):

Before Laravel 5:

- `{{{ $var }}}` escapes the contents of $var
- `{{ $var }}` echoes $var unescaped

Since Laravel 5:

- `{{ $var }}` AND `{{{ $var }}}` escape the contents of $var
- `{!! $var !!}` echoes $var unescaped

Answer (score 4):

`{{{` renders HTML data but `{{` shows data and elements without rendering.

ex :

`$str = "<h3>Hello world!</h3>";`

`{{ $str }}` output : `<h3>Hello world!</h3>`

`{{{ $str }}}` output :

#### Hello world!

Answer (score 2):

In **Laravel 4** `{{{ $var }}}` is used to render data by escaping HTML entities that uses PHP `htmlentities` function to prevent XSS attacks.

`{{ $var }}` is used to render data without escaping HTML entities.

In **Laravel 5** it slightly different you can use either `{{ $var }}` or `{{{ $var }}}` to escape data and to render unescaped data you can use `{!! $var !!}`.

Answer (score 0):

Something I don't see mentioned here but which can be handy to know. If you have a translation text with a parameter that should become a Vue variable in the resulting html then the triple curly braces come in handy.

E.g.:

```
{{{ __('This window will close in :timeout seconds', ['timeout' => '@{{timeoutSecs}}']) }}}
```

Attempting this with any other combination of curly braces will throw some error.